# Something about the min

Tags: calculus, inequality

Why is $$e^{-x/\epsilon}(1-e^{-(x_i-x)/\epsilon})\leq \min\{e^{-x/\epsilon},\frac{x_i-x}{\epsilon}\}?$$ I know that $1-e^{-x}\leq x,\; \forall x\geq 0$ which probably gives the second term in min, $0<\epsilon<<1$ and $x_i>x$.

Comment: I think you have a typo... $\forall y\ge 0$?  Perhaps you mean $\forall x\ge0$

Comment: This is false for $\epsilon=1$, $x=10$, $x_i=9$. On the other hand, it holds if $x$ and $\epsilon$ are always positive and $x_i>x$.

Comment: It's a typo, I have corrected it. @HenningMakholm, $\epsilon$ cannot be 1 and yes $x_i>x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *additionally* you know that $x>0$, then $x/\epsilon$ and $(x_i-x)/\epsilon$ are both positive. Then your inequality follows from

$$ e^{-A}(1-e^{-B}) < \min(e^{-A},1-e^{-B}) \le \min(e^{-A},B) $$

for arbitrary positive $A$ and $B$. The factors on the left-hand side are both strictly between $0$ and $1$, so naturally the product is less than either. The second inequality is just $1-e^{-B}<B$ which you already know.

Comment: My problem is the first inequality. Could you elaborate.

Comment: @Vaolter: If $P$ and $Q$ are both strictly between $0$ and $1$, then $PQ<P$ and $PQ<Q$, and therefore $PQ<\min(P,Q)$ because $\min(P,Q)$ equals either $P$ or $Q$.